# How can i migrate my code from flutter_webview_plugin to webview_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview-flutter

I'm trying to update an old flutter project. But i'm having some problems with the *flutter_webview_plugin*, so i want to migrate to *webview_flutter*. The problem i have is that i don't know how to adapt the code so it can do the same.

Here is the flutter_webview_plugin code, the bold lines are the ones i need to change.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
final flutterWebviewPlugin = flutterWebviewPlugin(); //Need to change 
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {//Need to change 
      if (url.contains("https://www.laplata.com.py/")) {
        final urlResult = Uri.parse(url);
        flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('pay', arguments: urlResult.queryParameters);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final urlPagopar = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    if ( urlPagopar != null ) {
      return  SafeArea(
        child: WebviewScaffold( //Need to change
          hidden: true,
          initialChild: Center(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage( image: AssetImage('assets/loading2.gif') )
              )
            )
          ),
          url: urlPagopar as String,
        ),
      ); 
    }
    else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              delegate: SliverCustomHeaderDelegate(
                minheight: size.height * 0.15,
                maxheight: size.height * 0.15,
                child: _cabecera()
              )
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                SizedBox(
                  height: size.height * 0.85,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(),
                      Container( padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20), height: 300, child: SvgPicture.asset( 'assets/error.svg')),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      const Text("UPS!!!... Ocurrió un error inesperado", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const Text("Vuelva a intentarlo o comuniquese con nuestro contact center", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat", fontSize: 18)),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ])
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this below i just migrated today.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';
late final WebViewController _controller; 
bool loading=true;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();   
late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
  if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
     params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
     allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
     mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{},
     );
    } else {
      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
    }
  final WebViewController controller =
  WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params); 
  controller
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onProgress: (int progress) {
        loading = true;
        debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
    
        setState(() {});
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        print("url $url"); 
        loading=false;           
        setState(() {});
        
      },
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
       loading=false;
        setState(() {});
      },
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {          
      if (request.url.contains("https://www.laplata.com.py/")) {
           final urlResult = Uri.parse(url);        
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('pay', arguments: urlResult.queryParameters);      
          }            
       
      },
    ),
  )
  ..addJavaScriptChannel(
    'Toaster',
    onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
      );
    },
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlPagopar)); // url   
  if (controller.platform is AndroidWebViewController) {
    AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
    (controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController)
       .setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
   }  

_controller = controller;
}
```

and the build method is like

```
 Scaffold(      
  body: loading
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
);
```

and you need to add this two package [webview_flutter_android](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_android) and [webview_flutter_wkwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_wkwebview) for android and ios and import in this page

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is this: it is better to use flutter_inappwebview https://inappwebview.dev/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).